# Google Analytics: __utma not updating

Tags: google-analytics, session-cookies

We have noticed some odd behaviour from Google Analytics. It seems to be that the __utma session times not being updated any more.  We haven't ever used _setSessionCookieTimeout to set the time-out away from the default of 30 minutes.

As a simple test we cleared the cookies, logged in and then idled for 30 mins - but no luck, the __utma was not modified.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

A.

Comment: I tried setting the _setSessionCookieTimeout to be something small, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we were spamming GA on start up. **Newbie javascript error**. I cannot recommend  [GA Debug](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) enough!

```
var statusCodeReporter = 
{
    400: TrackView("Error", "400"),
    401: TrackView("Error", "401"),
```

Should probably be something like

```
var statusCodeReporter = 
{
    400: function() { TrackView("Error", "400");},
    401: function() { TrackView("Error", "401");},
```